# compare multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

if I have n number of lists like below

```
list1 = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'seven', 'nine', 'zero']
list2 = ['two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']
list3 = ['one', 'two', 'zero', 'three', 'seven']
list4 = ['four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']
list5 = ['zero', 'one', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'ten']
list6 = ['one', 'two']
```

and all elements are composed from some fixed items like below

```
list_main = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

the question is: I need to categorize lists according to occurrences so the result will be like this

```
list2, list4 -- because they all have same 5 items ('four', 'five', 'ten', 'six', 'eight')

list1, list3, list5 -- because they all have same 4 items ('zero', 'one', 'three', 'seven')
```

**EDIT**: like the example mentioned above

i want to put together the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop

as when i run the process again it will look in the remaining lists and find the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop and so on till there are no remaining lists.

Comment: This problem seems underspecified. Why group only list1, list3, and list5 together? Why not group list1, list3, list5, and list6 together? They all have the same 1 item `("one",)`.

Comment: Are you looking to create a group of list names for every shared element?

Comment: First figure out what you want.  Only then can you meaningfully think about how you might achieve it (and meaningfully ask for help if needed).

Comment: so you want all the list that have a certain group of elements?

Comment: It sounds as if you're trying to create list intersections.  There's a lot of information out there on how to do this with Python.

Comment: @Kevin  like the example mentioned above

i want to put together the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop

as when i run the process again it will look in the remaining lists and find the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop and so on till there are no remaining lists.

Comment: What does the data actually look like?

Comment: Also what should happen with 6?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 6 will be isolated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to start will be to sort all the sublists and rank each match:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def srt(args):
    for ind, sub in enumerate(args, 1):
        sub.sort()
        yield ind, sub


d = defaultdict(defaultdict)
orig = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]

all_best = defaultdict(int)

subs = sorted(srt(deepcopy(orig)), key=itemgetter(1))
for ind, ele in subs:
    best, partner = None, None
    for i2, ele2 in subs:
        if ind == i2:
            continue
        _int = len(set(ele).intersection(ele2))
        if best is None or best < _int:
            best = _int
            partner = i2
            if all_best[ind] < best:
                all_best[ind] = best
    d[ind][partner] = best
    d[partner][ind] = best

grouped = []

used = set()
for k, v in (d.items()):
    if all(val == all_best[_k] for _k, val in v.items()):
        best = [k] + list(v)
        if not any(s in used for s in best):
            grouped.append(best)
        used.update(best)

print(grouped)
print([[orig[ind-1] for ind in grp] for grp in grouped])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4]]
[[['one', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'seven', 'nine', 'zero'],
['one', 'two', 'zero', 'three', 'seven'],
['zero', 'one', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'ten']],
['four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']]]
```

Comment: but I got lists with same length not same elements intersection

Comment: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [['one', 'two']], 5: [['one', 'two', 'zero', 'three', 'seven'], ['four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']], 6: [['two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten'], ['zero', 'one', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'ten']], 7: [['one', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'seven', 'nine', 'zero']]})

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you how many items list1 and list2 have in common:

```
len(set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

You can do something like:

from collections import defaultdict

intersections = defaultdict(set)

```
lists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    # and so on
]
for i in range(len(lists) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(lists)):
        intsec = set(lists[i]).intersection(lists[j])
        intersections[tuple(sorted(intsec))].add(lists[i])
        intersections[tuple(sorted(intsec))].add(lists[i])
```

This will build a database of all the commonalities between the lists.
You can sort that based on the length of the key in intersections, i.e. the number of shared elements, but as soon as you start to exclude something because you saw it in another context before, you are making decisions based on arbitrary (?) ordering. There could be several different keys in intersections with a length of five for instance. Which should you keep, and which should be removed since they were a duplicate?

Comment: I can did it but if you look in EDIT I added to question you will know my goal
 like the example mentioned above i want to put together the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop as when i run the process again it will look in the remaining lists and find the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop and so on till there are no remaining lists.

Comment: I don't think this adds up logically.
imagine you have l1=[1,2], l2=[2,3] and l3=[1,3]
l1 and l2 have one in common.
i1 and l3 have one in common.
l2 and l3 have one in common.
This exclude from next loop approach means that arbitrary ordering impacts your results, right?

Comment: @Mangnus Lycka , once I got first one matching I will exclude them from the next loop

Comment: I got the following error when  running  the code
intersections[tuple(sorted(intsec))].add(lists[i])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Sorry, cast the list to a tuple:
intersections[tuple(sorted(intsec))].add(tuple(lists[i]))

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
>>> my_lists=[ list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6 ]
>>> my_list_of_set=[set(x) for x in my_lists ]
>>> my_list_of_set.sort(key=len) 
>>> result=[]
>>> while my_list_of_set:
        elem = my_list_of_set.pop()
        max_inter=max(map(lambda x:x&elem, my_list_of_set), key=len, default=set())
        inter = [ x for x in my_list_of_set if elem & x == max_inter]
        for x in inter:
            my_list_of_set.remove(x)
        inter.append(elem)
        result.append( (max_inter,inter) )

>>> for x in result:
        print("the matching elem:",x[0])
        print("the lists:",x[1])
        print()


the matching elem: {'three', 'one', 'zero', 'seven', 'four'}
the lists: [{'one', 'seven', 'four', 'three', 'ten', 'zero'}, {'one', 'nine', 'seven', 'four', 'three', 'six', 'zero'}]

the matching elem: {'five', 'six', 'ten', 'eight', 'four'}
the lists: [{'five', 'six', 'ten', 'eight', 'four'}, {'four', 'two', 'five', 'six', 'ten', 'eight'}]

the matching elem: {'one', 'two'}
the lists: [{'one', 'two'}, {'seven', 'three', 'one', 'zero', 'two'}]

>>>
```

first make all the lists sets so you can use intersections, and save then in a new list, sort say list by length and star by taking the longest one and search for the biggest intersection with the others, then make a list with all the elements that have the same biggest intersection and remove them and save the result

**Edit**

here is another approach to the problem

```
import operator as op
from itertools import chain, combinations
from functools import reduce
from pprint import pprint 
from collections import namedtuple

def powerset_since_n(iterable,n=0):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(n,len(s)+1))

Groups = namedtuple("Groups","sublist common_elem") # for esthetic reasons

def get_common_groups(ListOfList) -> "[ (indexs,common_elements) ]":
    """from the given list of list return a tuple with the index of the sublists that 
       have the maximum amount of common elements across the maximum amount of sublists 
       and a set of the common elements between them"""
    my_dict = {i:set(x) for i,x in enumerate(ListOfList)}
    order = sorted( my_dict,key=lambda x:len(my_dict[x]))
    all_inters = dict()
    #calculate all posibles not empty intersections of 2 or more sets
    for grupo in powerset_since_n(order,2):
        temp = reduce(op.and_, map(my_dict.get, grupo) )
        if temp:
            all_inters[frozenset(grupo)] = temp  #the frozenset is to make order irrelevant
    result=[]
    order_set = set(order)  # make this set so don't have to calculate it each time in the filter below
    while order:
        elem = order.pop()
        order_set.remove(elem)
        grupo = max( filter(lambda k: elem in k and k&order_set, all_inters)
                     ,key = lambda kk: 2*len(kk) + len(all_inters[kk])      #this is what decide who is the max
                     ,default=frozenset() # the empty case
                     ) 
        for x in grupo:  #remove the selects one
            if x in order_set:
                order.remove(x)
                order_set.remove(x)
        grupo_final = set(grupo)
        grupo_final.add(elem) # for the case in that the grupo is empty 
        result.append( Groups(grupo_final,all_inters.get(grupo,set())) )
    return result
```

this time first I calculate the power set of the given list of list, then starting with the longest list I decide which is the maximum group from the one that involve it and the remaining elements by adding how many lists are involve and how many elements they have in common, and to chose the one with more list in it I give extra weight to the number of lists involves and let *max* do its job and the rest is self explanatory.

Here a quick test

```
>>> my_lists=[ list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6 ]
>>> pprint(get_common_groups(my_lists))
[Groups(sublist={0, 2, 4}, common_elem={'seven', 'zero', 'one', 'three'}),
 Groups(sublist={1, 3}, common_elem={'ten', 'eight', 'five', 'four', 'six'}),
 Groups(sublist={5}, common_elem=set())]
>>> my_lists[0]
['one', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'seven', 'nine', 'zero']
>>> my_lists[1]
['two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']
>>> my_lists[5]
['one', 'two']
>>>
```

Comment: your solution looks very close, but why it didn't give us the answer of lists list1, list3, list5 -- because they all have same 4 items ('zero', 'one', 'three', 'seven')?

Comment: This solution only check for the largest intersection between 2 lists so because list1 and list5 have 5 elements in common while list3 only have 4 elements in common with any of them, then list1 and list5 are taken in the first group, then list2 and list4 are in the second group and the rest in the final group.

Comment: I noticed that when running the code with even odd number of lists it gives an error : " max_inter = max(map(lambda x: x & elem, my_list_of_set), key=len)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"

Comment: that is because you get no elements in common and a empty sequence don't have a max elements, to handle that case you can provide a default value for those cases: `max_inter=max(map(lambda x:x&elem,my_list_of_set),key=len,default=set())`

Comment: I update with another approach to the problem, this time it get the result from the example

Comment: Great, it was exactly what I need, Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103765/discussion-between-mohamed-yousof-and-copperfield).

Comment: when I use list of lists which generated from code it hangs  but worked when use predefined lists

Comment: mmm, how are thats list generated?

Comment: From user input in qtalewidget

Comment: qtalewidget? what is that?

Comment: Gui item, user can insert as many rows as he needs and insert data in it, I loop over rows and each row appended to list so I get list of lists

Comment: well, this function kind of expect a list of list fully builded, but it should work with a generator of those, because only iterate over the input once to transform it to structure it need to work, so maybe the problem is that you don't exit properly your gui stuff and is waiting for something like one the sub list... can you put the actual code of that so that I can test it?

Comment: I tried to pass list of lists to the function and got the same result,

Comment: You can try this,  full_list=[[1,2],[2,4],[5,7,2]] and pass it to the function

Comment: it work fine for my, with that example of `full_list=[[1,2],[2,4],[5,7,2]]` I get `[Groups(sublist={0, 1, 2}, common_elem={2})]`

Comment: I tried list of strings, actually I am out of office now and can't try again can you please try list of lists with strings not numbers?

Comment: something like this `get_common_groups(["ab","bd","egb"])`? from that I get `[Groups(sublist={0, 1, 2}, common_elem={'b'})]` it still work as I expect (a string is like a list of chars). Or this `get_common_groups([["1","2"],["2","4"],["5","7","2"]])`? from that I get `[Groups(sublist={0, 1, 2}, common_elem={'2'})]`.

Comment: Maybe I am using a misleading name with `sublist` in the namedtuple thing if so I apologize for that, I mean for that is the index of the sublist in the ListOfList (as I put in the doc of the function) because that is how I first thought the algorithms, but is you want the actual sublist in there that is easily fixed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point, what happens if you passed the following to the function? , full_list = [["one", "two"], ["one", "three"], ["one", "two", "three"]]

Comment: with that I get `[Groups(sublist={0, 1, 2}, common_elem={'one'})]`

Comment: actually it worked for me too but when I added many lists (33 lists) it takes too much time, I ran it 35 mins ago and it still processing till now, 
any how many thanks for your effort, great job :)

Comment: oh, I did not expect that you where to use that many list. This solution is highly inefficient because of the powerset, there is `2**n` elements in the powerset of a set of size n, so with 33 list is going to take forever or blow up your memory so don't use it to anything above 17, 20 top. The solution of **Padraic** look more promising and also produce the expected result with the example (to look it better change print for pprint), check that out with your 33 lists and if it work is easy to modify it to your liking...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll want to wrap your lists in another list:

```
lists = [['one', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'seven', 'nine', 'zero'],
         ['two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten'], ...]
```

Then, you'll want to act on all of the combinations of two lists in your `lists` list. `itertools` module can help you with that:

```
import itertools
for pair in itertools.combinations(lists, r=2):
  # each pair is a tuple of lists ([], [])
```

Then you can do stuff with intersects to select the most matching lists.
You want to get the intersection with the most elements in it. The finished thing looks like this:

```
import itertools
#Use your lists. I used those to test.
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
         [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         [3, 4, 5, 1],
         [8, 5, 6, 9, 2, 4]]

#Intersects a pair of lists and builds the dictionary
def intersect_pair(pair):
    return { 'intersection': set(pair[0]).intersection(pair[1]),
             'initial_pair': pair }

#Determines the intersection size for the 'max' function
def intersect_size(intersection):
    return len(intersection['intersection'])

#Intersects every pair and selects the largest intersection
pairs = [intersect_pair(pair) for pair in itertools.combinations(lists, r=2)]
most_matching_pair = max(pairs, key=intersect_size)

#This is the dictionary containing a pair of two most matching lists and their intersection.
print(most_matching_pair)
```

Comment: I need to categorize lists according to occurrences so the result will be like this

list2, list4 -- because they all have same 5 items ('four', 'five', 'ten', 'six', 'eight')

list1, list3, list5 -- because they all have same 4 items ('zero', 'one', 'three', 'seven')

like the example mentioned above

i want to put together the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop

as when i run the process again it will look in the remaining lists and find the most matching lists and exclude them from the next loop and so on till there are no remaining lists

Answer (score -1):

Ported to python3:

```py
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations

list1 = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'seven', 'nine', 'zero']
list2 = ['two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']
list3 = ['one', 'two', 'zero', 'three', 'seven']
list4 = ['four', 'five', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']
list5 = ['zero', 'one', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'ten']
list6 = ['one', 'two']



def varname(var):
    import inspect
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    var_id = id(var)
    for name in frame.f_back.f_back.f_back.f_locals.keys():
        try:
            if id(eval(name)) == var_id:
                return(name)
        except:
            pass

size=len([list1,list2,list3,list4,list5,list6])         
s={}        
l=['{varname(list%d):set(list%d)}'%(i,j) for i, j in zip(range(1,size+1),range(1,size+1))]
d=reduce(lambda x, y: {**eval(f'{x}'), **eval(f'{y}')}, l)

#for k1, a in d.items():
#    for k2, b in d.items():
#        if k1!=k2 and not (k2, k1) in s.keys() and not (k1, k2) in s.keys():
#            if int(k1[4])>int(k2[4]):
#                s[(k2, k1)]=len(a.intersection(b))
#            else:
#                s[(k1, k2)]=len(a.intersection(b))

#OR

#keys = combinations(d.keys(),2)        #<== keys
#values = map(lambda a: len(a[0].intersection(a[1])), combinations(d.values(),2)) #<== values           
#s={k:v for k, v in zip(keys,values)}

#OR

s={(a[0][0],a[1][0]): len(a[0][1].intersection(a[1][1])) for a in list(combinations(d.items(), 2))}


x={}    
for k, v in s.items():
    x[v]=x.get(v,[])+[k]
    print (v, ": ", k)

x=dict(sorted(x.items()))
for k, v in x.items():
    for tpl in v:
        print (k, "times: %s intersects with "%str(tpl), ":", list(eval('set(%s)'%tpl[0]).intersection(eval('set(%s)'%tpl[1]))))
```

**list l should be:**

```
['{varname(list1):set(list1)}',
 '{varname(list2):set(list2)}',
 '{varname(list3):set(list3)}',
 '{varname(list4):set(list4)}',
 '{varname(list5):set(list5)}',
 '{varname(list6):set(list6)}']
```

**dict d should then be:**

```
{'list1': {'four', 'nine', 'one', 'seven', 'six', 'three', 'zero'},
 'list2': {'eight', 'five', 'four', 'six', 'ten', 'two'},
 'list3': {'one', 'seven', 'three', 'two', 'zero'},
 'list4': {'eight', 'five', 'four', 'six', 'ten'},
 'list5': {'four', 'one', 'seven', 'ten', 'three', 'zero'},
 'list6': {'one', 'two'}}
```

**we have s as intersection list:**

```
{('list1', 'list2'): 2,
 ('list1', 'list3'): 4,
 ('list1', 'list4'): 2,
 ('list1', 'list5'): 5,
 ('list1', 'list6'): 1,
 ('list2', 'list3'): 1,
 ('list2', 'list4'): 5,
 ('list2', 'list5'): 2,
 ('list2', 'list6'): 1,
 ('list3', 'list4'): 0,
 ('list3', 'list5'): 4,
 ('list3', 'list6'): 2,
 ('list4', 'list5'): 2,
 ('list4', 'list6'): 0,
 ('list5', 'list6'): 1}
```

**x then is s in key/value is a grouping of keys in s for its value, then ordered for occurance:**

```
OrderedDict([(0, [('list3', 'list4'), ('list4', 'list6')]),
             (1,
              [('list1', 'list6'),
               ('list2', 'list3'),
               ('list2', 'list6'),
               ('list5', 'list6')]),
             (2,
              [('list1', 'list2'),
               ('list1', 'list4'),
               ('list2', 'list5'),
               ('list3', 'list6'),
               ('list4', 'list5')]),
             (4, [('list1', 'list3'), ('list3', 'list5')]),
             (5, [('list1', 'list5'), ('list2', 'list4')])])
```

**Final printed result is just pretty printed:**

```
0 times: ('list3', 'list4') intersects with  : []
0 times: ('list4', 'list6') intersects with  : []
1 times: ('list1', 'list6') intersects with  : ['one']
1 times: ('list2', 'list3') intersects with  : ['two']
1 times: ('list2', 'list6') intersects with  : ['two']
1 times: ('list5', 'list6') intersects with  : ['one']
2 times: ('list1', 'list2') intersects with  : ['four', 'six']
2 times: ('list1', 'list4') intersects with  : ['four', 'six']
2 times: ('list2', 'list5') intersects with  : ['four', 'ten']
2 times: ('list3', 'list6') intersects with  : ['one', 'two']
2 times: ('list4', 'list5') intersects with  : ['four', 'ten']
4 times: ('list1', 'list3') intersects with  : ['seven', 'zero', 'one', 'three']
4 times: ('list3', 'list5') intersects with  : ['seven', 'zero', 'one', 'three']
5 times: ('list1', 'list5') intersects with  : ['seven', 'one', 'four', 'three', 'zero']
5 times: ('list2', 'list4') intersects with  : ['five', 'four', 'six', 'eight', 'ten']
```